# Parse string as long in Java

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String args[]) {
     String blah = "1073841824.000000000000";
     Long longVersion = Long.parseLong(blah);
     System.out.println("Long : " + longVersion);

}


}
```

When I try and print the result I get:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
 string: "1073841824.000000000000"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
          at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
         at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
         at Test.main(Test.java:5)
```

String `blah` represents an amount, 1 gigabyte. I can't just remove the zeros, there will be cases where these won't be all zero. I am not sure if `Long` is the correct type to use here.

Comment: look more like a `double` than a `long`

Comment: Can you confirm: the string after zero is the number's fractional part?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to use a primitive type, use should use double. Long can't handle decimals. But instead of double you should use the BigDecimal class. It's made for big numbers and handles Strings directly. For example:

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(blah);
```

Comment: Really bad advice. As long as the number in the string isn't too big, there is **absolutely** no need to turn to BigDecimal. Also note that BigDecimal is about floating point numbers.

Comment: @GhostCat, judging how OP says that "after dot they might not be all-zeroes", I too think it's a fit for either `double` or `BigDecimal`. There's no confirmation that fractional part is significant though.

Comment: It is indeed about floating point numbers. And a BigDecimal would be more suitable in the given case, because it won't cut off floating points if there would be more than allowed by double. I don't agree with your opinion. @GhostCat please don't blame answers before reading the question

Comment: The title says: parsing string as long. Anyway, not much point arguing about a question that has been asked and answered many times before.

Comment: @Joel: BigDecimal worked perfectly, thanks. The fractional part is significant as I stated in my post.